# AdaptiveSubmitAction is not working on mobile app

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have developed a custom teams app which is a message extension using bot framework v3 (c#). I'm having a adaptive card with a submit button, this button trigger AdaptiveSubmitAction, its working on desktop teams app but on mobile version this is not working.
Is there anything I have add to make this work on mobile app also.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say it's not working? Does the submit action not send a message to your bot or is the message different or what? Also, are you talking about the Android app or the iPhone app or what?

Comment: I'm taking about the Andriod app, and i'm unable to figure out whats going wrong as on submit button click nothing is happening.

Comment: Do you have the bot running locally (e.g. with ngrok)? If so, when you click the button on the Android device, do you see a call come in on Ngrok, or nothing at all?

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal Thanks for reporting this. We could repro this and i have raised a bug for this.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT - I cannot reproduce this. Submit actions work fine for me in Teams 1416/1.0.0.2019121201 on Android 8.0.0 OCXS27.1.7. What environment are you able to repro this in?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT, I'm trying to use the app on Andriod 9.0  in Teams 1416/1.0.0.2019121201 on my one plus 5 device

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal I have tested this on the latest build and raised a bug for this. The team is looking into this.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT, you have tested and found the same issue?

Comment: @Mayuresh yes. I did.

Comment: @MayureshJaiswal - Why did you un-accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Gousia, this is a bug and is being looked into